# Iteration in Logic Apps terminates prematurely

Tags: iteration, azure-logic-apps, terminate

I'm using the Loop Until control in a Logic App, controlled by a simple counter. However, I find the loop terminates prematurely, so far fairly consistently after *about* 30 iterations, when I'm looking for much more (365 in fact - days of a year). The App doesn't fail, and looking at the run, it's clear the counter is working fine. Presumably the App has run up against an internal limit. I'm currently trying to use Analytics to dig deeper; will revert if any useful result. The only other thing worth mentioning is that I've set all loops to run sequentially i.e. no concurrency

Comment: You might want to consider of loading the looping work to a Function, as looping that many times in a Logic App you will hit limitations and also it will probably cost more in a Logic App than a Function App.

Comment: Thanks for that thought. Can you substantiate that? Any references?

Comment: See the comment at the bottom of  https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/looping-options-in-azure-logic-apps

Answer (score 0):

How do you set the count and Timeout limit in the Until connector?

Default limits are 60 iterations and one hour for timeout, if you exceed that limits, the until loop end before the condition is true.

Comment: Can you clarify please: I can see published limits in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#concurrency-looping-and-debatching-limits); it says 60 is the _Default_ Iteration limit; how can I increase this? Also, 1 hour is a low limit - where is this defined and how can I increase it. Thanks

Comment: I attached the detailed link, you should edit the "Change limits" on the designer mode (or in the JSON code "limit": { 
         "count": 60,
         "timeout": "PT1H"
      })                     https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#prevent-endless-loops

Comment: I had to go into code edit to change 60 limit to the desired value.