# Why Until loop ends earlier?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am performing an until loop in logic app. In this loop I'm using a delay function to do the next loop. But if we manage the delay unit to hour, the loop will end in the second time. That means the loop will only executed twice!(Escalation variable is 72 and LoopCounter increments from 0) I want to know if it is a bug from logic app or I did some wrong settings.
Please see the settings as below.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be with ['Until Loop'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#until-loop) **timeout**. To resolve this you can try the following ways:

It looks like this is due to a bug in the way we evaluate the **timeout limit value** in the until scope.

- Remove the triggerBody{} from the limit.timeout property – i.e. make a it a static value
- If you really need to make the timeout computation dependent on the payload of the trigger request, you may want to add the “triggerBody()” into the “expression” property of the “until” (this is because we parse the expression when loading dependencies before the action is run)

For example:
[image]

You can refer to [Configure Logic App 'Until Loop' timeout dynamically](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/48784d16-d7ac-4fcb-89e3-f4e2c0abc348/configure-logic-app-until-loop-timeout-dynamically?forum=azurelogicapps), [Iteration in Logic Apps terminates prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62068543/iteration-in-logic-apps-terminates-prematurely), [Until Loop Dynamic Count Limit](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/009c9210-bd24-4b03-8bdc-78fe62d4ab0c/until-loop-dynamic-count-limit?forum=azurelogicapps) and [Add the Delay-until action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-delay#add-the-delay-until-action)

Comment: it looks like the timeout setting value from limit is used for the entire loop?